# Tensorflow Error(tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError)

Tags: python, tensorflow

- Python version = `3.7.3`
- OS = `Windows 10`
- CUDA version = `10.1`

Error Code:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: cudaGetErrorString symbol not found
```

Comment: Could you please post a snippet of your code so we can help you troubleshoot? Looks like the compiler doesn't recognize `cudaGetErrorString`.

Comment: hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')

Comment: Tensorflow version? Make sure CUDA is the right version for it.

Comment: maybe least Tensorflow version

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code rather than in the comments where it's hard to find.. See [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.